# Cross-chain transaction not reflected

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, cross-chain

Some time ago I tried to transfer some (wrapped) Ethereum from BNB Smart Chain to Ethereum mainnet using https://app.crosschainbridge.org.

I would like to understand what happened since it looks like it wasn't received in the destination account as expected.

From what I see in the [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x04433de054aabf2bf0372761817e6a62917f8e4c21f32f651ba2eb20488ab9e8).

The transfer was done using an smart contract (0xcbce172d7af2616804ab5b2494102daec47b2635) and was indeed sent to an intermediary account and then to my Ethereum address.

However, when I look into my Ethereum address, I only see an internal transaction in which I receive the Ethereum but I cannot see it reflected on the balance.

It looks like I miss a something basic here but I can't guess what.

Can you help me shedding some light into this?

Comment: Does etherscan shows the correct balance? If the balance is correct then the bridge worked as expected. It is like that the problem is the wallet. There are some wallets that do not support internal transactions. If the balance isn't correct you should contract the bridge customer service.

Answer (score 0):

if you take a look on "logs" tab, you can find exact path of your tokens. Looks like it was transferred successfully as "Withdrawal" event was fired at success only.
But the final address is contact one - 0xCBCe172d7af2616804ab5b2494102dAeC47B2635

You can see from "TokenRelesed" event that from address (deposit) 0x2170Ed0880ac9A755fd29B2688956BD959F933F8
Tokens where sent to 0xAf1CdC67E03cddB41bC8272E49B5bb39C45AF7C3

If it is your address - that should be fine.